# What is the difference between req.path, req.params and req.query?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, json, express

Can someone explain the differences between `req.path`, `req.params`, `req.query` and `req.body` in node.js?

Comment: Could you please add your sample that you need to create? What is not working for you?

Comment: i am working with fake apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the entities you mentioned are used to send the data in the request except for the req.path. Its the way that are sent is different.

Here's an example to clear your thoughts:

**req.path:**

- The virtual path of the current request
- URL: https: // stackoverflow.com/questions/52926562
- Example: *req.path* will give you: 52926562

**req.params:**

- Gets a combined collection of QueryString, Form, Cookies, and ServerVariables items.
- www.dogsworld.com/1   (ROUTE: www.dogsworld.com/:dogId)

**req.query:**

- The query string variables sent by the client. Keys and values are URL-decoded
- www.dogsworld.com?breed=asian&name=tommy

**req.body:**

- Message Body
- Example:
  {
      name: "Tommy",
      breed: "Asian"
  }

Any updates are welcome!

Comment: Thanks dear i got it.it help me alot.

Answer (score 0):

req.path, req.params, req.query are basically part of route based action.
1. req.path : Return pathname of the given request url.
2. req.params: Used to get parameter value of a request url.
3.req.query: Used to get the query value embedded in request url.

Example: For url :https://your_url.com/52926562?value="test"

```
app.get('/:id', (req, res)=>{
    /*Return the path of the request*/
    console.log(req.path);
    /*Return the id of the request url*/
    console.log(req.params.id);
    /*Return the path of the request*/
    console.log(req.query.value);
    res.send('ok');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1) **req.path** is used for getting the current url is hitting by the user .

2) **req.query** is used for getting the query params in url.

3) **req.body** is used to get a request payload send by the user.